# how to load zend framwork 1.12 in yii?

Tags: php, zend-framework, yii

new zend framework 1.12 have new autoloader my old code for loading zend in yii was:

```
require "Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php";
Yii::registerAutoloader(array('Zend_Loader_Autoloader', 'autoload'), true);
```

now with upgrade to 1.12 it's not working 

any suggestions loading zend in yii ?

Comment: Why would you load a framework inside another framework?

Comment: as this framwork has some features that do not present in yii

Comment: IMHO you should then consider using ZF alone instead.

Comment: zen framework is so slow comparing to yii

Comment: Facts..? I'm curious since I was going to choose ZF2 for a project of mine!

Comment: yes for sure yii is faster, if you know socialengine it's a social network based on zend and it's too slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the autoloader code from your question with this:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

Just calling `Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()` will have the Zend Framework autoloader register itself with [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) which is all that `Yii::registerAutoloader()` tries to do.

Registering ZF's autoloader like this should allow you to autoload Yii classes and ZF classes together without any problems.